# Resolving factory methods for multiple implementations with autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

Given:

```
public class InfoA { /* impl */ }
public class InfoB { /* impl */ }

public class ViewModelBase {}
public class ViewModelA : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModelA(InfoA info, Dep1 dep1, Dep2, dep2) { }
}

public class ViewModelB : ViewModelBase 
{
    public ViewModelB(InfoB info, Dep3 dep3, Dep4 dep4) { }
}
```

How do I register types to my container such that I can do

```
class ViewModelRepository
{
     public ViewModelRepository(
         Func<InfoA, ViewModelA> factA, 
         Func<InfoA, ViewModelB> factB) { }
}
```

or alternately `Func<InfoA, ViewModelBase>` and `Func<InfoB, ViewModelBase>` ?

Currently I have

```
builder.RegisterType<ViewModelA>().As<ViewModelBase>()
builder.RegisterType<ViewModelB>().As<ViewModelBase>();
```

Which seems to only work for the type registered last.

Answer (score 0):

You can only resolve types you actually registered in the container. When you use `.As<TService>` method, it allows you to resolve dependencies by `TService` only.

So to resolve `Func<InfoA, ViewModelA>` you have to register `ViewModelA` the following way:

```
builder.RegisterType<ViewModelA>();
```

if you want to resolve it only by `ViewModelA`,

or

```
builder.RegisterType<ViewModelA>().As<ViewModelBase>().AsSelf();
```

if you want to resolve it by `ViewModelA` or `ViewModelBase`, although, as you already mentioned, it would not be possible to get `ViewModelA` directly by resolving `ViewModelBase`, because the default implementation is the type registered last (`ViewModelB` in your case), but you can still resolve all types of `ViewModelBase` using collection (e.g. `IList<ViewModelBase>`). `ViewModelB` should  registered the same way.

IMHO, you should introduce some interfaces in you code, as resolving dependencies by actual types is not exactly how you should do the dependency injection. Classes should depend on contracts (interfaces), rather than actual types, so they could be easily replaced, e.g. by mocks in unit tests.